# Add button with cell date to jQuery fullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Well I've been trying to make something like random plus button to each cell in full calendar grid and I've achieved it by using:

```
viewRender: function (view, element) {
    var add_url = '<a class="tip add-task" title="" href="#"\n\
        data-original-title="Dodaj zadanie"><i class="icon-plus"></i></a>'; 
    $(".fc-day-number").before(add_url);
 }
```

inside fullCallendar options.

But bow It would be nice if I could add some dates and time to urls, because after clicking plus button action will be redirected to some controller with form and dates on that form would be based on those taken from fullCallendar plus button.

So I need a cell date :P like.

```
href="\smth.php?date=8-10-2015"
```

But I have no idea hot to catch that date for each cell in view render.

Comment: Just use [dayRender](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/dayRender/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you notice that on fc-day-number

```
<td data-date="2015-01-16" class="fc-day-number fc-fri fc-future">16</td>
```

it has the date value for you, that could the be grabbed in the click event.

or as someone commented: dayRender you could add to the  its self whatever you wanted and have the date object available for building the custom button.